# How do I string interpolate a ng-template ID into the ng-if Else condition?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, string-interpolation, ng-template

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
  <ng-template [attr.id]="'tileInactiveContent'+user">
    something...
  </ng-template>
  <div *ngIf="somecondition;else tileInactiveContent+{{ user }}">
    something...
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above code, users is a string array of 4 strings.

Hence 4 ng-templates are generated in the final code with each ng-template having a unique id.

**Question**

How do I address the ids in the else part of ngIf directive ?
What is the replacement for ' tileInactiveContent+{{ user }} ' ?

I know that ng-template can be called with inversed if condition. But still..

Comment: Why using unique id for each iteration? creating a dynamic template variable is  impossible in angular

Comment: why do you want to include the user into the ng-template id?

Comment: @RafiHenig are you implying that *ngFor figures it out itself even with **same id** provided for all templates?

Comment: You are using the same template for all iterations,?

Answer (score 0):

Call Ts function from Template itself, and write the logic in that function

```js
getWhatever(index:any,user:User){
//do and return something
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let user of users;let i=index;">
  <ng-template [attr.id]="'tileInactiveContent'+user">
    something...
  </ng-template>
  <div *ngIf="somecondition;else getWhatever(i,user)">
    something...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: function binding is not good approach for performance, It always listen html

Comment: But how does this render the required ng-template _instead_ of the div?